# How to find unique elements from two HashSet objects

Tags: java, set, hashset

I have a two HashSet objects with elements `{A,B,C,D}` and `{A,B,X,Y}`. I need a third set with unique elements from both sets result will be like `{C,D,X,Y}`.

Comment: Your code ? what have you tried so far ?

Comment: look at `Set#retainAll()`

Comment: Isn't B unique?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for an implementation of [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).  See also [What is the best way get the symmetric difference between two sets in java?](/q/8064570) and [Symmetric difference of two sets in Java?](/q/8064570).  If you meant something else, you should probably [edit] your question to clarify what's different in your situation.